# How to measure the distance between two points in the same layer accounting for stream meandering in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, distance, flow-direction

I am trying to measure the distance (in meters) between points that are in the same layer and I would like to account for the distance of meanders in the stream if possible. I was able to calculate linear distance using the measure tool, although I am sure there is an automated and more efficient way of doing that. Is there a way to measure the distance between two points on a flow line?

Here is a photo example: I would like to measure the distance between points, from 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 and so on.

[image: Points on a flow line]

Comment: Are the red dots the only vertices on the line or just specific vertices along the line?  It seems like the latter since the line appears to curve/bend and spots that aren't red dots.

Comment: This is a task for liner referencing but you can try https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346127/calculate-sequential-numbers-along-line#346311

Comment: There are several methods, linear referencing or using network analysis tools built into ArcPro. If you have ArcMap consider using RivEX, a tool for extracting such information from river networks, the tool you would want to use is [this](https://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Buildalinktonearestsiteswithinal.html).

Comment: @bixb0012 The red dots are a separate layer than the polyline layer. The polyline layer is a NHD Flowline layer and point layer is sample points on the stream. I would like to find the distance between each sample point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although flow lines are a natural use-case for [linear referencing](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/linear-referencing/introduction-to-linear-referencing.htm), building a linearly referenced data set isn't trivial.  In this specific case, it isn't necessary so it definitely isn't worth the effort.

If you have a Map with NHD flow lines and a feature class with points that are near or on the flow lines, you can use [Split Line at Point (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-point.htm) to split the flow lines into new segmented flow lines where you can [Calculate Geometry Attributes (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm) to add the length in units you want.  *I suggest using selection sets against the NHD flow lines and points to cut down the new feature class to interested/specific flow lines*
[image: NHD Flowlines and Break Points]

[image: Segmented NHD Flowlines]